# Delphi search for text after a defined character

Tags: delphi

I have a string

```
String :='this is my string | yes';
```

I need delphi to get whatever the text is after the |

So something like:

```
getTextAftertoCharacter('|',String);
```

This should return "yes" in the example above.

Has Delphi get a function for this?

Comment: Are you sure to get `'yes'` from `'this is my string | yes'`, because then the current answers are wrong, because the text after `'|'` is `' yes'` :o)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not aware of a single function that does this. I think the easiest way would be to use `Pos` and then `Copy`:

```
answer := Copy(str, Pos('|', str) + 1, Length(str));
```

Start character is at `Pos('|', str) + 1`, amount of characters to copy is actually `Length(str)-Pos('|', str)`, but passing a greater value to `Copy` also works.

Note: this will return the whole contents of `str` if there is no `'|'`. Check for `Pos('|', str)` being non-zero if you need different behavior.

Comment: Prob. should check for Pos returning 0?

Comment: Good point, thanks. I'm not sure what is the desired answer if the string does not contain `'|'`. Will update the answer.

Comment: `Copy(str, Pos('|', str) + 1);` is enough to get the rest

Comment: Indeed. But that form of Copy was first introduced in XE3?

Comment: @Inspired Nope, AFAIK I used this a long time before XE

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Controls.GetLongHint()`:

```
GetLongHint(String);
```

That's because the separator of a two part hint is a `|`. In your example it would return ' yes', with the leading space. If `|` is not found, the function returns the `String`.

Comment: Yeah, but only if the char is `|`. And still I think it's a bit semantically strange to use a function named `GetLongHint` if you don't want a 'long hint'.

Comment: Creative solution :) +1

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52397/discussion-between-craig-young-and-sertac-akyuz)

Comment: As @Andreas says: "_I think it's a bit semantically strange to use a function named GetLongHint if you don't want a 'long hint'_". There are usually 2 problems with with using "semantically strange" code: **(1)** Code is harder to read, understand and maintain. **(2)** And in _some cases_ there can be a risk that the implementation is changed in such a way that the side-effect no longer does what you want. (In this case `GetLongHint` is safe because its semantics are unlikely to change.)

Comment: I chose to downvote because I see this answer as encouraging a bad habit (use of semantically strange code).

Comment: @Craig - For (2) - This answer does not use `GetLongHint` for its side effect. It is the sole purpose of `GetLongHint` to return the string that's after the first `|`. There's no other "long hint" that would infer a different meaning to a Delphi developer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use then following code:

```
Trim(RightStr(Text, Length(Text)-LastDelimiter('|', Text)));
```

It'll locate the last delimiter in the string and I used Trim to get rid of the whitespace. LastDelimiter can take more than one delimiter which may be usefull. If no delimiter is found it will return the whole string.

Comment: What if the input will be `this is my string | yes, TLama | is pedant :)`. It sounds like the OP wants to get text after the first occurence of the `|` char rather than from the last one. But who knows...

Comment: "is pedant :)" All depends on what you want the function to do :)